# Pros and Cons of Engaging Manager More

Tags: communication, management, manager

My manager has an open door policy. This is pretty awesome.

I frequently see other co-workers utilizing this. I also do, but probably once every month or so where others are in there once a week or every other day etc. I generally think I know where I stand with my performance and other matters, so I tend to think that frequency usually works well. I am also pretty laid back and care free, probably more so than most people.

so.

> Are there any / what are the pros and cons in talking to my manager more often since the opportunity is there?

I feel like more communication cannot hurt, but at the same time too much is just noise.

Comment: Hey Joshua, I feel that you are asking us to make a *choice* for you (yes/no do it), which is [off-topic](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site. Perhaps you could rephrase your question to make it on-topic... some ideas I have are: *"What could be the pros and cons of talking to my manager more often?"*, or *"Are there any possible downfalls in increasing my visits to my manager's office?"*... or perhaps there are other that better fit your question.

Comment: I'm married to a manager and her biggest complaint every day is adults acting like children and the workers bringing every little thing to her instead of thinking for themselves.  If that helps.

Answer (score 5):

If you have no reason to do it then don't.

For many managers the best employee is the one who just buckles down to the work, always seems positive and you rarely hear from. So if you have a reason then by all means use your manager as a resource, but if you start looking for petty reasons your manager may think you need your hand held a lot.

Another advantage is if someone rarely comes with a question, they will often get a lot more attention precisely because they're known not to bother anyone unless it's work related and important.